# change localhost to local ip adress of pc when host application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, networking, iis-7, localhost

Hey,
I host my asp.net application with wcf service on IIS 7 and I want that this location could be possible at adress of my computer in lan, that other in network could get to it..
It is possible?

Now it looks like: http://localhost/wcfAx/Service1.svc
How to do like that : http://192.168.2.33/wcfAx/Service1.svc   ??

Comment: You shouldnt need to do anything extra for that This link http://192.168.2.33/wcfAx/Service1.svc should work provided 192.168.2.33 is the IP address of your m/c. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for that not to work... Providing that 192.168.2.33 is the address of your machine on the network, and that your firewall permits traffic through port 80.

Comment: I have firewall which block connection to that ip :/ Now it's ok ;)